# Do the compass roses on the hidden map mean anything?

Tags: civilization-6

While playing I noticed some odd circles on my mini-map (marked with red):

[image: Mini-map with odd circles]

These turned out to be compass roses that also emit lines on the hidden part of the map:

[image: A compass rose, also emitting lines.]

Since their on what appears to be specific locations and also are shown on the mini-map, I thought they might be where they are for some reason. Online I couldn't find anything about it though.

**So do these compass roses have any meaning or are they only cosmetical?**

#### Edit:

Creatures that are appear on hidden parts of the map also show up on the mini-map:

[image: Some creature on a hidden part of the map.]

[image: The mini-map with a hidden creature on it.]

So the question applies to them as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe they are cosmetic.

From memory, in the lead up to the release of Civ VI the developers mentioned that they changed the Fog of War to look like an ancient map, rather than the White Clouds of V, or the Black from earlier games. The developers have never mentioned anything about the Fog Of War having changed it's purpose in Civ VI.

The purpose of the Fog of War in Civilization games has always been to obscure the unexplored sections of the map. It would go against this purpose for that Fog to give you clues about what you have not found, and such a big change would have been mentioned.

Finally, in my 700+ hours of playing Civ VI I have never noticed any patterns, or indication that these map pictures mean anything at all. As you said, you can't find any mention of it online, and I am sure that across untold thousands of hours played by the player base someone would have noticed if there was a pattern.

Comment: Accepted this answer as it answers my question and also gives the reasoning behind it, instead of the short answer of @Keelhaul.

Comment: The compass roses have nothing to do with the Fog of War - they appear in the areas you haven't discovered yet. Fog of War is the term for the area you discovered but don't watch right now so can't see who's there.

Comment: https://civilization.fandom.com/wiki/Fog_of_war

Comment: The Civ community use the term differently, so I used it the way they use it.

Answer (score 8):

It's purely cosmetic, in order to look like an old map as we usually represent them.
I know this is a rather short answer, but there's nothing more to say, really.

Comment: Appropriate for someone named Keelhaul to answer a question about (maritime symbols on) old maps.

Comment: No problem if it's short if it is complete. But I still miss the reason why you know this to be the case.

Comment: Wikipedia has a list of old maps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_world_maps#After_1492 . For compass roses, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_world_maps#/media/File:Caverio_Map_circa_1506.jpg and for monsters, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_world_maps#/media/File:OrteliusWorldMap1570.jpg . Better examples might be present - I had a quick look only.